# Apply software settings to all logged in user accounts

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-settings

Currently using Windows Server 2008 R2

I have created custom settings for a software and I want to apply it to all users on the domain, regardless of where they sit. Is it possible to apply these settings to an OU?

The settings have to be pasted to their user folders manually as of now from the admin account, and in order that any user can log into any computer on the domain we have to log all users manually, into all computers any shortcut to doing the same ?

Comment: What exactly are these "software settings" -- registry values, files (you mention "pasting")? Are you looking to do this with Group Policy/Client-Side Preferences, a script, something else?

Comment: 2 files have to be pasted one is a  config files and one is a shortcut file that has to be pasted on each user account in the app data folder.

Comment: I was thinking of possibly using group policy

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Group policies are the way to go. In 2K8R2 you have the new group policy preferences built-in which enable you to create files on user computers (of course presuming, that your users/computers all are managed in an AD domain), which sounds exactly like the thing you want to do.

You can apply group policies to OUs and with group policy preferences you can use additional targeting conditions).

The "old" solution would be to create startup scripts and associate those either via GPO as well or use the "old" user profile solution.